# How to prove $(p\implies q)\land(r\implies s)\land(p\lor r)\implies (q\lor s)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Here is my attempt to prove this implication, but I got stuck.

$$
(p\implies q)\land(r\implies s)\land(p\lor r)\implies (q\lor s)\\
(\neg p\lor q)\land(p\lor r)\land(r\implies s)\\
[(\neg p\lor q)\land p]\lor[(\neg p\lor q)\land r]\land(r\implies s)\\
[(\neg p\land p)\lor(q\land p)]\lor[(\neg p\lor q)\land r]\land(r\implies s)\\
\dots
$$

eventually it expands very very long, I believe these is a short cut to rearrange to have a nice form rather than expand all of it to arrive $(q\lor s)$

Appreciated for any help.

Comment: Use [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination)

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that when we have the hypotheses and $\lnot q$, we can derive $s$.

From contraposition, the first implication in our hypotheses gives us $\lnot p$. From the third we must then have $r$, and finally from the second we have $s$.

Symbolically, this is rearranging the statement to read $$[(\lnot q \Rightarrow \lnot p) \land(\lnot p\Rightarrow r)\land (r\Rightarrow s)] \Rightarrow (\lnot q\Rightarrow s)$$ and proving the final statement using repeated modus ponens.

Answer (score 0):

One way is the [method of analytic tableaux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux).

You start with the negation of your formula then apply some contradiction-hunting rules to deduce that it is impossible, like so:

[image]

This proof tree was generated [here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((p%E2%86%92%20q)%E2%88%A7(r%E2%86%92%20s)%E2%88%A7(p%E2%88%A8r))%E2%86%92%20(q%E2%88%A8s)).